# Parallel deployment of express nodejs application to multiple application servers

Tags: node.js, git, express, deployment, capistrano

I have a mean.io express/node js web application deployed on a Linode stack.

I have my 2 application servers running Ubuntu 14.04, which are accessed behind 2 **Haproxy** load balancers again running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Let us call Application server 1 => **APP1** and Application server 2 => **APP2**

Currently, I deploy manually by

1. Removing **APP1** entry from haproxy.cfg of both the load balancers and restarting.
2. Update the code on **APP1**
3. Remove **APP2** entry from haproxy.cfg of both the load balancers and put **APP1** entry back
4. Restart **APP1**
5. Update code on **APP2**
6. Put the **APP2** entry back in both haproxy.cfg's and restart
7. Restart **APP2**

I follow this process so that at any point of time the users of our web application get consistent data even during deployment, i.e both the instances of app server are not running a different copy of the code.

I am moving to automated deployment system and the 2 options I have looked at for deployment are **Capistrano** and **Shipit JS**.

They both provide ways to mention multiple servers in their configuration, for e.g in **capistrano**

```
role :app, "APP1", "APP2"
```

and in **Shipit JS**

```
shipit.config.servers = ['APP1', 'APP2']
```

1. So, my question is how do these libraries make sure that both the servers are updated parallely before they are restarted? Is there a way by which they lock incoming requests to these servers during updation ?
2. Do these deployment systems work only for simple **Client - App Server** architecture or they can used in systems where there is a load balancer?

Any explanation would be invaluable. I have tried my best to explain the situation here.If you need more input please mention below in the comments.